# Let react dev accessing staging from workstation: bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, development-environment, staging

We have 3 environements: Dev (local to their workstation) -> Staging -> Production

React developers wants to have access to staging backends in order to have *real* data and work with *real* use cases.

Despite the fact that React developers argue that this is harmless as they can't make any modification I feel uncomfortable about letting them use staging as their own testing backend.

I mean... of course, a staging environment should be isolated from dev and production environments (at least in theory). But how can they be efficient if they have to host backend environement with manual DB sync themself on their workstation ?

Is it a bad practice ? How would you do it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a business rule/decision.

Comment: Regardless of my close vote, my two cents: keep environments *separate* to avoid introducing artificial dependencies, "oops mistakes", and (if it ever matters) data exposure.

Comment: The secondary question ("How to implement ..?"), isolated as a separate question, may be more appropriate to SO - but would require more / specific context. In my organization, for instance, we have separate SQL Instances (and segmented networks) - including a *shared development database cluster* - for each environment. Thus, developers can work on a shared Development-Integration data-set/schema without affecting Automation-Testing / Test / Staging / Production environments. Schema and reference-data is promoted and sync'ed as relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think using staging as a backend environment for local frontend development can be a reasonable thing to do, but a lot is going to depend on the specifics of the app and company. Just practically speaking, if it ends up simplifying things for your frontend team and doesn't cause other problems, seems like an alright thing to do.

There are certainly other options as well:

- Create a third environment that serves as the backend for frontend development, leaving staging and production alone. Oftentimes, staging might need to be used for testing a release, so it can be nice to have a third environment that always holds the latest changes that a developer may need to work on.
- Each developer is able to provision and spin up their own environment running somewhere remotely (aws, gcp, etc), perhaps with different versions of backend services.
- Run everything locally (ideally just a matter of running something like docker compose) and seeding data.

Between the four options (using staging, using a new third environment, each developer has their own remote environment, and running locally), it's then a matter of looking at the tradeoffs of each approach and optimizing for your app/business.

New remote environments obviously have a monetary cost to them and probably requires some work to get going.

Running everything locally doesn't, but it may slow down your developers, or may eat up a lot of computing resources if you have a lot of services and db's.

Using your staging environment is probably the lowest effort, since the environment is already there. If there aren't obvious problems with doing so, it's probably worth trying out and investing time/resources in another option if there end up being problems caused by using it for this purpose.